# VBA to pull all TABs into one and include TAB name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on VBA code to pull all content on the tabs into one tab. All works great, except I cant get TAB file names included. I have over 200+ tabs and I need to get all content from them put on one tab (data structure is the same) but also include tab name in one of the column (preferably column A).This is what I have so far:

```
Sub FuLL_LIST_MERGE()
'
' FuLL_LIST_MERGE Macro
'

'
Dim ws As Worksheet
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(0).Clear
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
ws.UsedRange.Copy
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FuLL_LIST_MERGE()
'
' FuLL_LIST_MERGE Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet, n As Long

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(0).Clear

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        n = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A1").Resize(n, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(n) = ws.Name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SJR !!! However, in each of those sheets there are between 1 to   100 lines, but 200 lines formatted (have lines borders ect.). So what's happening now is that this script takes 200 lines for the TAB name (as 200 lines are formatted in each cell) but it only takes 1-100 text from sheets. So in other words, I have  1753 lines pasted from all sheets, but 40042 lines in column A with dates.

```
Sub FuLL_LIST_MERGE()
'
' FuLL_LIST_MERGE Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(0).Clear

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count) = ws.Name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Couln't get this to work so used clear format VBA and it worked... However it would be nice to have a solution how to get it working without clearing formats, if anyone has some time ...

`Sub clear_format()
Dim ws As Worksheet

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(0).Clear

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        ws.Cells.ClearFormats
    End If
Next

End Sub`

Comment: OK, have amended code above. If the number of columns of data is fixed, could be adapted to incorporate that, but the amendment should at least not copy the empty rows which have been formatted.